# Mobx-state-tree doesn't rerender on a new Map reference

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react, mobx-state-tree

Quite new to mobx-state-tree. Whenever my model is changed so that a types.map gets a new reference, my component is not rerendered.
In my example, changing a string on the model does trigger a rerender.
I'm reading both of these properties inside the component I wish to rerender and have decorated it with `@observer`.

Here's a Stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-n54mud

Comment in line 37 to make it work.

Model:

```
export const treeModel = types
    .model({
        tree: types.map(types.string),
    test: ''
    })
    .actions(self => ({
        setTree(tree) {
      self.tree = tree
    },
    setTest(data) {
      self.test = data;
    }
    }));
```

App

```
class App extends Component {
  treeStore;

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React'
    };

    this.treeStore = treeModel.create();
    this.treeStore.setTree(new Map());
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.treeStore.setTree(new Map());
      // Enabling this will retrigger the rendering of the Test comp
      //this.treeStore.setTest('azerty');
    }, 2000);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Hello name={this.state.name} />
        <p>
          Start editing to see some magic happen :)
        </p>
        <Test store={this.treeStore}></Test>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Test component

```
@observer
class Test extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
      console.log('rendered');
      const {tree, test} = this.props.store;
      return <div>test</div>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your treeStore should be `@observable`

```
class App extends Component {
  @observable treeStore;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`types.map` is not your regular `Map` (*although it has similar methods*) and while it would have been logical to expect that it can accept a `Map`, apparently it doesn't (*maybe you should file an issue about it on their [tracker](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-state-tree/issues)*). However to solve your immediate problem, simply pass an object in your `setTree` action, or - array of arrays:

```
this.treeStore.setTree({ 'one': '1' });
```

or

```
this.treeStore.setTree([[ 'one', '1' ]]);
```

Comment: In my actual example, I can't use objects as my Map has 'non-string' keys. So unfortunately not a real option for me. Thx for the answer though.

Comment: You can use array of arrays then. I mentioned it, and updated my answer with an example now.